# Urllib2 downloads broken binary data

Tags: python, urllib2

Here is sample code of downloading images using urllib2:

```
for photo in getListOfPhotos('Anouk'):
    with open(photo[0]+'.jpg','w+') as f:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(photo[1])
        answer = response.read()
        while answer:
            f.write(answer)
            f.flush()
            answer = response.read()
```

(assuming that `photo` is list where first item is file name and second item is link)

But I get broken pictures (with green lines, red squaers etc). What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `'wb'` instead of `'w+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `urllib.urlretrieve` to download an image, you pass the image url and the `directory/name_to_save_as` as the second parameter.

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve(image_url,"locataion_to_save")
```

Comment: downvote for what exactly. It shows a much easier method to download an image